# export p12 file from command line

Tags: bash, export, keychain

I try to automate the process of apps building.
The function is  that,we have build a customer portal where the client can upload their files (cert, p12, provision) to our Mac server and the Mac will automagically build their application, properly signed,then,the client can download the ipa file which they want.

the problem is :
the p12 file should be exported from keychain,we can open the keychain,choose the .cer file,and export the .p12 file(including set the password),now ,I want to do these process from command line.client just need give us the name of .cer,then Mac server can export .p12 file automatically(the client don't need to export the p12 file from keychain by themselves).Do we can solve that question?

If Mac server get the.P12 file , .cer file need also to be sent ?

If you can give me some other field about this project,it also will help me so much.

thank you very much!

Comment: How do you do it so far?..

Comment: I have same question. Do you find the answer ? please share with me.